# spark <console>:12: error: not found: value sc

Tags: scala, apache-spark, distributed-computing

I wrote the following:

```
val a = 1 to 10000
val b = sc.parallelize(a)
```

and it shows error saying:

```
<console>:12: error: not found: value sc
```

Any help?

Comment: sc ie. Spark Context has been made available when the shell started

Comment: "made available when the shell started". Or rather, it hasn't. Provide more details about the steps you took to get to that error?

Comment: are there any import statements or classpath changes before this in the repl?

Comment: @GovindSinghNagarkoti wow so much observation talents WOW :)

Answer (score 3):

In my case I  have spark installed on local windows system and I observed the same error but it was because of below issue

Issue:Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: **The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable**.

This was because of permission issue.I resolved it by changing the permissions using below command.Though log says "on hdfs" this is on windows system

E:\winutils\bin\winutils.exe chmod 777 E:\tmp\hive

Answer (score 2):

It happens when your classpath is not correct. This is an [open issue](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6502) in Spark at the moment.

```
> spark-shell 

...
...
14/08/08 18:41:50 INFO SparkILoop: Created spark context..
Spark context available as sc.

scala> sc
res0: org.apache.spark.SparkContext = org.apache.spark.SparkContext@2c1c5c2e

scala> :cp /tmp
Added '/tmp'.  Your new classpath is:
...

scala> sc
<console>:8: error: not found: value sc
```

You may need to correct your classpath from outside the repl.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error, because `sc` is not defined. I would try:

```
sc = SparkContext(appName = "foo")
```

---

Another thing that usually happens to me is not getting a Kerberos ticket in the cluster, because I forgot too.

---

As for the "open issue in Spark" mentioned by Solnanki, I am pretty sure this is *not* the case any more.

Comment: Comment by another user: Response: Code above yielded a warning about SparkContext not taking any parameters. So just try: `val sc = SparkContext`

That fixed my issue

Answer (score 1):

First check the log file after spark-shell command run
whether SparkContext is initinalized as sc.
if SparkContext is not initialized properly

you have to set the IP address in spark environment.

Open the env file in **conf/spark.env.sh** and add the below line

export SPARK_LOCAL_IP="127.0.0.1"

Answer (score 0):

I hit this error when trying out Spark on Cloudera Quickstart VM. Turned out to be an hdfs file permission issue on `/user/spark`.

I could not switch to user "spark", I got a user not available error.
Changing file permissions with the below command solved it for me.

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chmod -R 1777 /user/spark

scala> val data = 1 to 10000
data: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170...
scala> val distData = sc.parallelize(data)
distData: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:14
```

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same problem. In my case the JAVA_HOME was not set properly which cause this issue. surprisingly SPARK would start but the sc context had issues creating an instance. When i fixed the JAVA_HOME to point to the correct java directory, this issue was resolved. I had to close the session and re-open a new one in order to ensure the path is updated and fresh session is turned on.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [this thread](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/CDH-Manual-Installation/Permission-denied-user-root-access-WRITE-inode-quot-user-quot/td-p/4943), one solution may be to switch off permissions checking.

> In cloudera manager, go to hdfs configuration under advanced and put the following code in  "HDFS Service Advanced Configuration Snippet (Safety Valve) for hdfs-site.xml" :

```
<property>
<name>dfs.permissions</name>
<value>false</value>
</property>
```

After that, it is necessary to restart the HDFS component.

It worked for me. It might not be appropriate for a production environment, however.