# Getting the below error, while I am execution the command spark-shell. Due to this the spark session and sqlContext is not getting initialized

Tags: apache-spark

**The below is error I am getting when I execute the spark-shell command.**

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':
      at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$reflect(SparkSession.scala:981)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:110)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:109)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$getOrCreate$5.apply(SparkSession.scala:878)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$getOrCreate$5.apply(SparkSession.scala:878)
      at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
      at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
      at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
      at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
      at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:99)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:878)
      at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:95)
      ... 47 elided
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog':
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$reflect(SparkSession.scala:978)
      ... 58 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog':
      at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState$.org$apache$spark$sql$internal$SharedState$$reflect(SharedState.scala:169)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.<init>(SharedState.scala:86)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sharedState$1.apply(SparkSession.scala:101)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sharedState$1.apply(SparkSession.scala:101)
      at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sharedState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:101)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sharedState(SparkSession.scala:100)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.<init>(SessionState.scala:157)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.<init>(HiveSessionState.scala:32)
      ... 63 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rw-rw-rw-
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState$.org$apache$spark$sql$internal$SharedState$$reflect(SharedState.scala:166)
      ... 71 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rw-rw-rw-
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:264)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:366)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:270)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.<init>(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:65)
      ... 76 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rw-rw-rw-
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:192)
      ... 84 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rw-rw-rw-
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(SessionState.java:612)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:554)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:508)
      ... 85 more
    <console>:14: error: not found: value spark
           import spark.implicits._
                  ^
    <console>:14: error: not found: value spark
           import spark.sql
                  ^
    Welcome to
          ____              __
         / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
        _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
       /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.0
          /_/


Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_144)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203815/spark-console12-error-not-found-value-sc#25204489

Comment: It is not helpful, sqlContext and sparksession are not available

Answer (score 0):

Probably you hit this : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10528

Just ensure the /tmp/hive is writable to the user who is trying to initiate spark-shell.

Thats it, it should take you through.

Comment: Few things, do I need to explicitly create the directories tmp/Hive and give permissions.

Comment: Another one I can see that a folder named metastore_db is getting created when I am execute spark-shell.